# How to access Values from ScriptableObjects in a List?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a list of Skills (ScriptableObjects) that have a Variable called Power needed for use in a my DamageFormula. Currently, the Power variable is ignored because of the Skill being in a List?. I tested that out by making a public reference to BaseSkill(the base ScriptableObject where all skills dervice from) and  dragging a skill directly into the slot in the inspector and it worked that way

This does not work - Power = BaseSkill.Power as that sets it equal to the power in BaseSkill ScriptableObject script which has no value because the Power Value is being set in the actual Skills so Its returning a "Object not set to and instance of a Object" and "

How do I set Power Int to be equal to the Power of my Skills from a List?

Comment: Please add your code.

Answer (score 1):

Create a scriptable object that holds your skills. Drag and drop your skills into the list.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu (fileName = "SkillStore", menuName = "SkillSystem/SkillStore")]
public class SkillStore : ScriptableObject
{
public List<Skill> skills;
}
```

Then reference it from GameManager or wherever you want. Assign skill store scriptable object from hierarchy.

```
public SkillStore skillStore;
```

Now you can call like that

```
int power = skillStore[skillIndex].Power;
```